# Symfony FOSRestBundle body listener conflict with SOAP WebService

Tags: web-services, api, symfony, soap, fosrestbundle

I developed a Symfony2 application with a SOAP WebService (with the PHP SoapServer class) for receiving data of a third application and now I'm developing an API with FOSRestBundle for the user interface. The problem is that with the configuration that I set for the REST bundle my SOAP WebService doesn't work throwing the following error:

'Invalid xml message received (400 Bad Request)' by 'FOS\RestBundle\EventListener\BodyListener' at line 71.

Here is my FOSRestBundle configuration:

```
fos_rest:
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    body_listener: true
    format_listener: true
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
        formats:
            xml: true
            json : true
        templating_formats:
            html: true
        force_redirects:
            html: true
        failed_validation: HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
        default_engine: twig
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
    serializer:
        serialize_null: true
```

If I set body_listener to false the SOAP WebService works fine, but I need set it to true for my RESTful API PUT requests. I tried out different configuration combinations but I can't fix the problem.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is there any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The following line in the bodylistener does not return an array, that's why it fails:

```
$data = $decoder->decode($content, $format);
```

Either the header for your request is invalid or the content your sending is not wel formatted.

Comment: Yes, the problem is decoding the content, the XmlDecoder is returning an UnexpectedValueException. But I don't know why because without the FOSRestBundle PHP & Symfony were decoding the content correctly. The content is SOAP Content-Type: soap-env/xml. I solved the problem disabling the body listener for XML, for my particular case I can do this because the API I am developing is JSON.